# Using generator instead of nested loops

Tags: python, iteration, generator, nested-loops

I have the following nested loop. But it is inefficient time wise. So using a generator would be much better. Do you know how to do that?

```
x_sph[:] = [r*sin_t*cos_p for cos_p in cos_phi for sin_t in sin_theta for r in p]
```

It seems like some of you are of the opinion (looking at comments) that using a generator was not helpful in this case. I am under the impression that using generators will avoid assigning variables to memory, and thus save memory and time. Am I wrong?

Comment: A generator is different but it won't be faster.

Comment: What makes you think a generator would be faster? It is not a magic bullet, only a means of avoiding having to materialize the whole result in memory. Since you are producing a list *anyway*, a generator will not offer any benefits and you'll just pay the overhead price for a generator.

Comment: I wonder if this is a salvageable question. Maybe the original asker could be told why it's downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from your code snippet you want to do something numerical and you want to do it fast. A generator won't help much in this respect. But using the `numpy` module will. Do it like so:

```
import numpy
# Change your p into an array, you'll see why.
r = numpy.array(p) # If p is a list this will change it into 1 dimensional vector.
sin_theta = numpy.array(sin_theta) # Same with the rest.
cos_phi = numpy.array(cos_phi)

x_sph = r.dot(sin_theta).dot(cos_phi)
```

In fact I'd use `numpy` even earlier, by doing:

```
phi = numpy.array(phi) # I don't know how you calculate this but you can start here with a phi list.
theta = numpy.array(theta)

sin_theta  =numpy.sin(theta)
cos_phi = numpy.cos(phi)
```

You could even skip the intermediate `sin_theta` and `cos_phi` assignments and just put all the stuff in one line. It'll be long and complicated so I'll omit it but I do `numpy`-maths like that sometimes.

And `numpy` is fast, it'll make a huge difference. At least a noticeable one.

Comment: This simplifies things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`[...]` creates a list and `(...)` a generator :

```
generator = (r*sin_t*cos_p for cos_p in cos_phi for sin_t in sin_theta for r in p)
for value in generator:
    # Do something
```

Comment: Your code still uses loops. My data is huge and using loops is inefficient. I am looking for a faster way. Thank anyways!

Comment: Using [generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)) won't magically make your code faster. You need to understand the basic principles behind it. A generator by itself won't do _anything_, as you need to _iterate_ over it to get the values. The main advantage is that the processing time distribution is different (you don't compute all the values at once, but on a as-needed basis)

Answer (score 0):

To turn a loop into a generator, you can make it a function and `yield`:

```
def x_sph(p, cos_phi, sin_theta):
    for r in p:
        for sin_t in sin_theta:
            for cos_p in cos_phi:
                yield r * sin_t * cos_p
```

However, note that the advantages of generators are generally only realised if you don't need to calculate all values and can `break` at some point, or if you don't want to store all the values (the latter is a space rather than time advantage). If you end up calling this:

```
lst = list(x_sph(p, cos_phi, sin_theta))
```

then you won't see any gain.

Comment: Your code still uses loops. My data is huge and using loops is inefficient. I am looking for a faster way. Thank anyways!

Comment: @jonrsharpe is right, based on your materialization of the list.

Comment: There is nothing inefficient about loops *per se*; `numpy` may be faster, but it's still looping somewhere in the background.